# SVG layer with hole

Tags: css, svg

I have found an SVG layer on the net. There should be a transparent hole in it. But I don't know how to change the colour around the hole from black to e.g. `#5BBB74`.

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 50" width="100%">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" fill="#fff"/>
      <circle cx="50" cy="20" r="10" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity=""/>    
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `fill` property to the rect affected by the mask.

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 50" width="100%">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" fill="#fff"/>
      <circle cx="50" cy="20" r="10" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="" fill="#5BBB74"/>    
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats works fine.. I will accept your answer as soon as the time lock is gone. 